# Air pressue inside a squeezed plastic bottle

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Ambient air pressure is 14.7 psi or 101 kPa. I understand there are lots of variables. But is it possible to roughly estimate the air pressure inside a water filled, hand-squeezed, 1 litre, plastic bottle with a 6mm ID exit tube reducing to a 0.8mm exit oriface?

Comment: Roughly as in "within an order of magnitude?"  This will depend heavily on the strength of people's hands.

Comment: Are you saying that air is in the head space, and you want to estimate the pressure of the air when you squeeze the bottle?

Answer (score 0):

For an ideal gas (which is a good approximation of air under normal atmospheric conditions), pressure times volume is a constant if the temperature of the air and the amount of air (the number of air molecules) is constant.

Thus, if you halve the volume, the pressure will be twice the initial pressure.